# Stripe Initial Payment Gateway Partner

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, banking, bank, onlinebanking

I'm not sure if this is the right platform to ask these questions, but I will delete and ask in the right one if I'm wrong.

Questions are as follows:

1. Which company was Stripe first payment gateway partner before they decided to build everything in-house.
2. Even after Stripe built everything in-house, it would still mean a direct relationship with some banks because they aren't a bank themselves, right?
3. For any FinTech company that's not utilising other FinTech's service (Banking-as-a-service, Payment Gateway API Integration), they would need to have this direct partnership with a more traditional kind of bank or Visa/Master, is that right?
4. If anyone has experience working or starting a FinTech company, I'd just like to ask if there's any difference in the Tech Stack, methodology etc. compared to a non-FinTech kind of startup, say a SaaS startup.

Thank you.

Comment: Your instincts were right unfortunately - Stack Overflow isn't the right place for this type of question because it's focused on banking more than programming. I'm not aware of a better Stack Exchange site to put this on and I suspect there's very few people in the world that know about Stripe's internals that are willing to share those details.

Comment: "a more traditional kind of bank  or Visa/Master" I think the Googlable buzz word you're looking for is [_Acquiring Bank_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acquiring_bank)

Comment: @HPierce Me too since I'm a frequent user of only stackoverflow itself, so I'm not familiar with other sites under Stack Exchange. Maybe I should post one on Quora.

The first question is of relative low priority though, I'm just curious how a technical person would be able to venture into the FinTech world. If the founders of a new Neobank, Payment Gateway, Digital Wallet etc. came from the banking world then they probably have the know-hows. Maybe the Stripe founders already have connections to acquire the know-hows I guess.

Comment: @HPierce Thanks, that's the proper term that I need, which leads to Issuer, Card networks etc.